# WebDeploy to server causes asp.net trust settings to reset to default

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webdeploy

I have an asp.net mvc application I am deploying to goDaddy using WebDeploy. Everytime I use webdeploy it resets the CAS trust level on the server requiring me to login and change it back to full and then everything works.

I am aware of  in webConfig settings but I am wondering if there is some setting in the webdeploy configure or elsewhere that I may be missing and could be causing this to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the web.config settings to a web.config transform and have them added during the publish using the transform

Once you publish, via Web Deploy, those settings will be migrated out to GoDaddy's server.

You may have to check the live web.config file after making changes in an admin console if that's how you're reapplying them on GoDaddy's side